# Using TPUs with PyTorch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to use Google Cloud's TPU from Colab. I was able to do it following the tutorial by using Tensorflow.

Does anybody know if it is possible to make use of the TPUs using PyTorch?
If so how can I do it? Do you have any example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out our repository [pytorch/xla](https://github.com/pytorch/xla) where you can start training PyTorch models on TPUs.

Also, you can even use free TPUs on Colab with PyTorch with these [Colab notebooks](https://github.com/pytorch/xla/tree/master/contrib/colab).

Comment: Thank you so much for the hard work! This is a major milestone!

Answer (score 9):

Currently, it's not possible to use Cloud TPU with PyTorch since it's designed specifically for Tensorflow.

But, according to [this product news posted three days ago in the Google Cloud blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/introducing-pytorch-across-google-cloud), "engineers on Google’s TPU team are actively collaborating with core PyTorch developers to connect PyTorch to Cloud TPUs".

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

As of today, [PyTorch Lightning](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning) allows to run PyTorch code on TPUs trivially (you will need the XLA library installed).
From their demo notebook on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-_LKx4HwAxl5M6xPJmqAAu444LTDQoa3):

```
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer

model = CoolSystem()

# most basic trainer, uses good defaults
trainer = Trainer(num_tpu_cores=8)
trainer.fit(model)
```

Comment: I tried to run the documentation collab and this is the error that I get:

`module 'torch_xla.core.xla_model' has no attribute 'rendezvous'`